# When the fibers of $A \to A[T]/(h(T))$ are geometrically regular?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an affine commutative noetherian domain over a characteristic zero field $K$, $T$ an indeterminate, $h=h(T) \in A[T]$ (not necessarily monic), $B=A[T]/(h)$, and assume that $(h)$ is a prime ideal (so $B$ is also a domain) and $B$ is flat over $A$.

What additional conditions are needed in order to obtain that the fibers of $A \to B$ are geometrically reular? Examples: (1) $fd_{B \otimes_A B}(B) < \infty$ implies that the fibers of $A \to B$ are geometrically reular, see [Theorem 1](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02566621). (2) Formal smoothness, according to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199416/are-the-fibers-of-this-morphism-geometrically-regular). (3) Maybe if $h$ is monic then we get geometrically regular fibers?

The problem with the first and second examples is that I do not know how to show that $fd_{B \otimes_A B}(B) < \infty$ or formal smoothness; probably one can find counterexamples, namely one can find $A$ and $h$ as above such that  $fd_{B \otimes_A B}(B) = \infty$ / $A \to B$ is not formally smooth.

Any help will be appreciated.